# Connect to streams additional to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR from Java

Tags: java, shell, process

In a Java process which is started by a native process (Yate telephony engine's extmodule) through a shell script, it is possible to connect to STDIN and STDOUT to communicate with the process and write log messages to STDERR.

The description of Yate's extmodule however mentions two additional file descriptors 3 and 4:

```
The external user application or script comunicates with the module trough several file descriptors:

    0 (stdin) - Carries commands and notifications from engine to application
    1 (stdout) - Carries commands and answers from application to the engine
    2 (stderr) - Has the usual meaning of reporting errors and is directed to the engine's stderr or logfile
    3 (optional) - Transports audio data from the engine to the application
    4 (optional) - Transports audio data from the application to the engine 

File descriptors 3 and 4 are open only for audio capable applications.
```

Is it possible at all to connect to those optional file descriptors and if yes, how? I know I can use `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err` for 0, 1, and 2 but what about the additional ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Yate is another process, and you're running on Unix / Linux / Mac OS (for Windows it might work as well, I simply don't know), you could redirect Yate's file descriptors 3 and 4 to pipes and then use Java to access these pipes.

It might also work, if you have a `/proc` file system or something similar, to access the files via the `/proc` file system.

You say java is started (i.e. forked) from Yate. In that case, yet another possibility would be "hacking" `FileDescriptor`. Currently, `FileDescriptor` is a pseudo-enum with only three instances, `in`, `out`, and `err`, corresponding to `0`, `1` and `2` respectively. The API itself can create other valid instances of FileDescriptor, but uses native code to do so. I do not know of a way through the normal Java API to open a file known by the numeric file descriptor (which is sad, Oracle, are you listening?!). You could write your own native code to do so, but beware, that's basically like open heart surgery.

Comment: I think too that redirecting the file descriptors to pipes is a solution. Meanwhile I found this about C to Java interprocess communication: http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~beardj/CtoJava.html
Thanks also for the insight on `FileDescriptor`!